# Confused about advantages of MockUp vs Expectations

Tags: java, jmockit

I just started using JMockit and am confused about the advantages of using MockUp for "Faking it" vs Expectations to mock an object.

From what I read through the docs, MockUp of a class allows me to override methods with my own implementations.  However, I see that I can do things similarly in Expectations blocks.

So what is the advantage of a MockUp vs an Expectations?  According to the [JMockit docs](http://jmockit.org/tutorial/Faking.html#mocks),

> Fakes are different from the mocking API in that, rather than
>   specifying in a test the invocations we expect a dependency will
>   receive when used by code under test, we modify the implementation of
>   the dependency so that it suits the needs of the test.

Isn't that just semantics?  Functionally, are the same things not achievable using an Expectations() block instead of using a MockUp<>?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is: What is difference between using Expectations and Mockup API?

I'm new to this, but to me that is mostly two different ways of doing the same thing. Which you pick is just matter of taste and how you want to test your code.
In Mockup API you can specify the mock in one statement block, whereas in Expectations you would use an Expectations block and a Verifications block. Otherwise they seem very similar to me too.